# C++ Int array type in function call

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I have an array initialised like the following:

```
int example[5][5];
example[5][5] = 55;
```

And a function:

```
void example_function(auto inArray, int z){
    cout << "example text = " << inArray[z][z] << endl;
}
```

And I am calling it into the function like this:

```
example_function(example, 5);
```

As you can see, I have the parameter for the function as auto when it is really using an integer array.

When I use `typeid(table).name()` to get the type of the array `example`, it outputs the type as `A5_A5_i` where the fives are from the initialisation (e.g. `int example[3][4][5]` would output `A3_A4_A5_i`)

When using `typeid(table).name()` on `inArray` after changing the type of the parameter from `int` to `auto`, I get the type name as `PA5_i` which is different to the one mentioned above.

How can I get a suitable type for a parameter in my function, and is there a better way to do this

Comment: 1) Your `example_function` doesn't even compile due to `inArray` being declared as `int inArray`, and being used as `inArray[z][z]`. 2) How is the entire example is related to what is printed when using `typeid`? Please provide [mre], providing what was output, alongside your wants/expectations.

Comment: I have the feeling that you expect something from `typeid` that it doesn't provide you, though I also dont understand what that is ;)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you for your response - It just seemed that my C++ knowledge was not as great as yours so I did not know how to use my array as a parameter for the function, so I would use "auto" instead of "int", but in my original question I did not change that. Thank you for letting me know about having to create minimal reproducible examples as I usually try to do that anyway, but in this case I forgot to assign values to the array in my example :)

Comment: @Forp 1) "_I did not know how to use my array as a parameter for the function_" It stands to reason, that if one talks about "outputs" in the question, one has access to functioning C++ compiler, with which one can test their example, before posting a question about it. 2) "_Thank you for letting me know about having to create minimal reproducible examples_" If you had read the link, you would see that your example isn't [mre]. If you had taken the [tour], and read through [ask], and [help], **before asking** (as is expected), you would've known that [mre] is expected.

Comment: @Forp 3) "_but in this case I forgot to assign values to the array in my example_" `example[5][5] = 55;` doesn't do that either. It assigns a value `55` to an out-of-bounds memory location, inducing undefined behavior in the process. This is the reason, why it is strongly recommended to learn from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of coding randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array passed to the function is known beforehand, in this case as `int example[5][5];`, you can use the following,

```cpp
void example_function(int (&inArray)[5][5], int z){
    cout << "example text = " << inArray[z][z] << endl;
}
```

Here we take the array by reference to avoid [array decay.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-array-decay-in-c-how-can-it-be-prevented/)

If the size might vary at runtime, use `std::vector`.

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> example;

void example_function(std::vector<std::vector<int>> inArray, int z){
    cout << "example text = " << inArray[z][z] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! I didn't know I had to specify the dimensions of the array in the paramaters (but strangely not as an argument).
I think the whole typeid thing may have distracted me too much.